# Regex to match url that starts with http or slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string that starts with either http:// or /.

This will pass...

```
http://www.google.com
/the/path/home.aspx
```

I'm pretty sure this will match http but I can't figure out how to fit in the optional `/`

```
/^(https?:\/\/)/i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *alternation operator* (`|`), like that:

```
/^(\/|https?:\/\/)/i
```

More details **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
/^((https?:\/)?\/)/i
```

Comment: As a note to others not so well versed in regexes on how this works (since it's a little bit of "thinking outside the box"), it says that `http:/` (optional `s`) is optional, and then a `/` is mandatory. This conveniently ends up matching `http://`, `https://`, and `/`, since the last `/` is mandatory in all cases. The other answers using `|` are just as valid, this is just an alternate way to think about it.

Comment: I gave Expert System the answer because I used his first but this I really like the creativity. Thanks for the insight Sean

Answer (score 2):

Use the "OR" operator which is denoted by the symbol `|`, like so:

```
/^(https?:\/\/|\/)/i
              ^^^
```